# CSS3 TransformY To Top

Tags: css

I am trying to create an effect like a water bubble is coming from bottom of the page to the top like bubble gets up from the water using CSS3 and I am total lost doing this.

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/youmere/HYZTm/4/)

Can you guide me if I can really give a effect like the bubble is coming from bottom to top?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to use CSS3 to take the top or bottom value from one number to another.   You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/t9Kyj/.

You can't apparently CSS3 transition from:

```
top: auto;
bottom: 0;
```

to

```
top: 0;
bottom: auto;
```

So, some others ideas are to find a different CSS method of specifying top and bottom position that will do a CSS3 transition for or programmatically set top/bottom based on the window height.